# find all palindromes in string

Tags: java, loops, palindrome

I need to find all the palindromes in a string. It takes user input

**example:** "abbaalla"

it loops through creating a substring that changes as the loop progresses.

**example**: checks palindrome "a" (true) "ab"(false) "abb" (false) "abba" (true) and so on..

once it reaches the max length of the word it iterates the start of the substring and repeats

**example**: check palindrome "b" "bb" "bba" and so on..

I need to change the code so that once it finds the first largest palindrome ("abba") the start of the loop will take place after that substring. so the next palindrome should read "alla"

the final output should be a string that includes all palindromes. in this case;

output: "abba alla"

Also this program currently results in: String index out of range: -1

```
 public static String findAllPalindromes(String input){
     int indexStart = 0;
     int wordMax = input.length();
     int wordLength;
     String checkPalindrome;
     String allPalindromes = "";
     for (wordLength = 2; wordLength <= wordMax; wordLength++) {

         //creates a substring to check against isAllPalindrome method
         checkPalindrome = input.substring(indexStart, wordLength);
         //checks checkPalindrome string to see if it is a palindrome
         if (isAllPalindrome(checkPalindrome) == true){
             allPalindromes += " " + checkPalindrome;
             if (checkPalindrome.length() >= allPalindromes.length()){
                 allPalindromes = checkPalindrome;
             }
         }
         //once program reads string through once, increment index and scan text again
         if (wordLength == wordMax && indexStart < wordMax){
             indexStart++;
             wordLength = 0;
         }

     }
     System.out.println("The palindromes in the text are: ");
     System.out.println(allPalindromes);
     return allPalindromes;
 }
```

Comment: it is a homework assignment and i have given so many attempts at creating a solution to the problem. looking for help from a friendly community

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public static Set<CharSequence> printAllPalindromes(String input) {
    if (input.length() <= 2) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
    Set<CharSequence> out = new HashSet<CharSequence>();
    int length = input.length();
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        for (int j = i - 1, k = i; j >= 0 && k < length; j--, k++) {
            if (input.charAt(j) == input.charAt(k)) {
                out.add(input.subSequence(j, k + 1));
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Add single characters on your own - it's trivial.

Comment: Without changing the current code, how can i avoid the string index out of range error?

Comment: @kealtuve: in your (question) code: A `substring` method takes as 2nd parameter **index** not **length**, so you have two bugs: 1) for condition should be `wordLength < wordMax` 2) `input.substring(indexStart, indexStart+wordLength)`

Comment: @jw23: Does it cover the case of String = "aab" where palindromes are "aa, a, b"?

Comment: This way covers only the odd palindromes, without the individual characters.

Comment: for input string string -'adda' is giving empty set, any thoughts?

Comment: @chipmunk - no it covers only palindromes that are at lest 2 characters long.
By wikipedia: "sequence of characters which reads the same backward or forward" so to have a sequence you need at least 2 characters.

Comment: @PraveenChinthala: Try again. Please. (code updated)

Comment: this program doesn't consider `aba` as palindrom.

Answer (score 6):

Simple Brute force way-->

```
public class AllPalindromes {

    public static boolean checkPalindrome(String str) {
        for(int i=0;i<=str.length()/2;i++)
            if(str.charAt(i)!=str.charAt(str.length()-1-i))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public static void printAllPalindrome(String str) {
        for(int i=0;i<=str.length();i++)
            for(int j=i;j<str.length();j++)
                if(checkPalindrome(str.substring(i,j+1)))
                    System.out.println(str.substring(i,j+1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printAllPalindrome("abbaalla");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution which displays all palindromes. (Only those palindromes which are of length greater than 3. You can change the if condition inside the loop if you want to print them all.)

Note that @jw23's solution does not display the palindromes which are of even length — only the odd length ones.

```
    public class HelloWorld{

    public static void printPalindromes(String s) {
        if (s == null || s.length() < 3)
            return;

        System.out.println("Odd Length Palindromes:");
        // Odd Length Palindromes
        for (int i=1; i<s.length()-1; i++) {
            for (int j=i-1,k=i+1; j>=0 && k<s.length(); j--,k++) {
                if (s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(k)) {
                    if (k-j+1 >= 3)
                        System.out.println(s.substring(j, k+1) + " with index " +j+ " and "+k);
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nEven Length Palindromes:");
        // Even Length Palindromes
        for (int i=1; i<s.length()-1; i++) {
            for (int j=i,k=i+1; j>=0 && k<s.length(); j--,k++) {
                if (s.charAt(j) == s.charAt(k)) {
                    if (k-j+1 >= 3)
                        System.out.println(s.substring(j, k+1) + " with index " +j+ " and "+k);
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "abcbaaabbaa";
        printPalindromes(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Palindrome
{
  static int count=0;
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1=sc.next();
    String array[]=s1.split("");
    System.out.println("Palindromes are :");
    for(int i=0;i<=array.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            String B=s1.substring(j,i);
            verify(B);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n"+count);
    sc.close();
  }
  public static void verify(String s1)
  {
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(s1);
    String s2=sb.reverse().toString();
    if(s1.equals(s2))
    {
        System.out.print(s1+" ");
        count++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My own logic for palindrome program for all substrings

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "bob";

        ArrayList<Character> chr = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<String> subs= new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            chr.add(s.charAt(i));
        }

        System.out.println(chr.toString());
        StringBuilder subString = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i < s.length();i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++)
            {
                for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
                {
                    subString.append(chr.get(k));

                }
                System.out.println(subString.toString());
                subs.add(subString.toString());
                subString.setLength(0); 
            }
        }

        System.out.println(subs);

        for(String st : subs)
        {
            String st2 = new StringBuffer(st).reverse().toString(); 
        if(st.equals(st2))
        {
            System.out.println(st+" is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(st+"  not a palindrome");
        }   

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question:  All the palindromes from a word.

```
public class Test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         String a = "ProtijayiMeyeMADAMGiniiniGSoudiptaGina";
        allpalindromicsubstrings(a);

    }// main

    private static void allpalindromicsubstrings(String a) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            // odd length palindrome
            expand(a, i, i, set);
            // even length palindrome
            expand(a, i, i + 1, set);

        } // for
        set.parallelStream().filter(words -> words.length() > 1).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
    }// ee

    private static void expand(String a, int start, int last, Set<String> set) {
        // run till a[start...last] is a palindrome
        while (start >= 0 && last <= a.length() - 1 && a.charAt(start) == a.charAt(last)) {

            set.add(a.substring(start, last + 1));
            // expand in both directions
            start--;
            last++;

        }
    }// ee

}
```

The output palindromes in the word =>
niin
ADA
eye
MADAM
iniini
GiniiniG
ii
MeyeM
ini

Print all the palindromes in a string:

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           String a = "Protijayi Meye MADAM GiniiniG Soudipta Gina";
           List<String> list = Arrays.stream(a.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toList());
          System.out.println(list);
          List<String> plist = new ArrayList<>();
          for(int i = 0 ; i <list.size();i++) {
              String curr =list.get(i);
              if(ispalin(curr)) {plist.add(curr);}
          }//for
          System.out.println("palindrome list => " +plist);

}//main

    private static boolean ispalin(String curr) {
        if(curr == null || curr.length() == 0) {return false;}
        return new StringBuffer(curr).reverse().toString().equals(curr);
    }

}
```

The output is: palindrome list => [MADAM, GiniiniG]

Another Method in Java 8:

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "Protijayi Meye MADAM GiniiniG Soudipta Gina";
        List<String> list = Arrays.stream(a.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // list to stream
        // for Multi Threaded environment
        Stream<String> stream = list.parallelStream();

        // also,Stream<String> stream = list.stream(); for single Threaded environment
        long palindrome = stream.filter(B::isPalindrome)// find all palindromes
                .peek(System.out::println) // write each match
                .count();// terminal - return a count
        System.out.println("Count of palindromes: " + palindrome);
        // System.out.println("List => " + list);


    }

    private static boolean isPalindrome(String aa) {

        return new StringBuffer(aa).reverse().toString().equals(aa);

    }
}
```

Output:
GiniiniG
MADAM
Count of palindromes: 2

Answer (score 0):

Print All Palindromes in the string

```
import java.util.*;
class AllPalindroms
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    String input = "abbaalla";      
    if (input.length() <= 1) 
    {
        System.out.println("Not Palindrome Found.");
    }
    else
    {   
        int length = input.length();            
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i <length; i++)
        {
            //if(i==0)
            for (int j=i+1;j<length+1;j++) 
            {
                String s = input.substring(i, j);                   
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
                sb.reverse();

                if(s.equals(sb.toString()) && s.length()>1)
                {                       
                    set.add(s);
                }
            }
        }           
        System.out.println(set);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code to count all palindromes in a string:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountPalindromeSapient {
    static int count = 0;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the given string: ");
    String inputStr = sc.nextLine();

    countPalindrome(inputStr);
    System.out.println("\nTotal count of Palindromes are: "+count);     
    sc.close();
}

private static int countPalindrome(String inputStr) {

    int count = 0;
    int len = inputStr.length();
    int startIndex =0;

    String subString = "";

    System.out.println( "Possible substrings are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = startIndex; j <= len; j++) {
            subString = inputStr.substring(startIndex, j);
            System.out.println(subString);

            count = checkPalindrome(subString);

        }
        startIndex++;
    }

    return count;
}

private static int checkPalindrome(String subString) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int subLen = subString.length();
    boolean isPalindrome = false;
    for(int k=0; k<subLen; k++,subLen-- ) {     // Important
        if (subString.charAt(k) != subString.charAt(subLen -1)) {
            isPalindrome =  false;
            break;
        }else {
            isPalindrome = true;
        }
    }
    if(isPalindrome == true) {
        count ++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
     class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringTest test = new StringTest();
         boolean bool = test.checkPalindrom("abbaalla");
        if(!bool)
            System.out.println("String is not palindrom");

    }
    private boolean checkPalindrom(String k){
        int[] count= new int[k.length()];
        boolean[] arr = new boolean[k.length()];
        for(int t=0;t<k.length();t++){
            int j=0;
            char ch = k.charAt(t);
            for(int x=t+1;x<k.length();x++){
            if(j<count.length){
                if(ch == k.charAt(x))
                    count[j] = x + 1;
                else
                    count[j] = 0;
                j++;
            }

            }
            arr[t] = workOnArr(count,t,k);
        }
        for(int z=0;z<arr.length;z++){
            if(arr[z])
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
private boolean workOnArr(int[] s,int z,String w){
    int j = s.length - 1; 
    while(j -- > 0){
        if(s[j] != 0){
            if(isPalindrom(w.substring(z, s[j]))){
                if(w.substring(z, s[j]).length() > 1){
                    System.out.println(w.substring(z, s[j]).length());
                    System.out.println(w.substring(z, s[j]));
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}   

private boolean isPalindrom(String s){

    int j= s.length() -1;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length()/2;i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j))
            return false;
            j--;
    }

    return true;
}
    }
```

output:-

given palindrom are:-

abba,  bb,  aa,  alla,  ll

Answer (score -2):

Java program to enter a string and frame a word by joining all the first character of each word.

Display a new word.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Anshu {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)
  System.out.println("Enter a string");
  String s = in .nextLine();
  char ch = s.charAt(0);
  System.out.print(ch);
  s = s.toUpperCase;
  int l = s.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
   char a = s.charAt(i);
  if (Character.isWhiteSpace())
   System.out.print(s.charAt(i + 1) + "");
 }
}
```